# Error occured when saving JavaScript file in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim, syntastic

When I save  JavaScript file in Vim, I always get this error.

> Error detected while processing function
>   107_BufWritePostHook[3]..107_UpdateErrors[15]..107_CacheErrors[20]..352[17]..359:
>       line    1:
>       E730: using List as a String
>       Error detected while processing function 107_BufWritePostHook[3]..107_UpdateErrors[15]..107_CacheErrors:
>       line   20:
>       E712: Argument of extend() must be a List or Dictionary

Don't know which plug-in is bad... Tried to search with error statement, but it did not work.

Please tell me how to examine.

Comment: This looks like a syntastic error, triggered by an invalid `syntastic_*_checkers`.  Please read the manual to find out the correct syntax for `syntastic_*_checkers`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just it was an error of that portion. It had become to `syntastic_*_checker`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `:scriptnames` to list all the scripts sourced by Vim. Number 107 is the script you are looking for.